# Static virtual IP in debian 6.0.4

Tags: networking, debian

In debian 6.0.4 my static ip is 192.168.1.151 and I want to add one more ip 192.168.1.175 as virtual ip. For did I made following changes in /etc/networking/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
#NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0

    iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.151
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255

auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.175
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

And when I run command

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a
```

I get the below information

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:87:fc:eb:b2:50  
          inet addr:192.168.1.151  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4687:fcff:feeb:b250/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:338433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:238153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:337480876 (321.8 MiB)  TX bytes:68577550 (65.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:25 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:494269 (482.6 KiB)  TX bytes:494269 (482.6 KiB)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:56:67:bf:36:84  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Mostly I get this but some time i get the virtual ip in the output. I have to make virtual ip permanent. How can i do that? Also I will assign this virtual ip (192.168.1.175) to two machine.

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart networking?

Comment: there's nothing "virtual" about the ip address you're assigning. It exists on the system, and is aliased to eth0. You'll therefor have problems if you assign this to multiple machines on the same network.

Comment: @sameer yes i restarted networking

Answer (score 1):

Alias/virtual interfaces are deprecated and should not be used. You should instead use iproute2 to add additional addresses to the actual interface:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.151
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    up ip addr add 192.168.1.175/24 dev eth0
```

To check the configured IP addresses use `ip addr show`.

Assigning the same IP to multiple machines will cause neither to work correctly though.

Comment: huh, just noticed that if you give a aliased device to `ip addr`, it just adds the address to the real device.

Comment: Yes, because aliased devices are an `ifconfig` hack to support multiple addresses.