# Adding IP address to existing network interfaces in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-16.04

I'd like to add a new IP address to an existing interface on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. I've looked at the file `/etc/network/interfaces` which defines the current IP addresses/interfaces and it has the following line at the top:

`source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*`

Is the right thing to do to place a new file into that directory with the configuration options, and then restart the networking service?

Also, is there a reason why the `source` directive is at the top of the file? Given that I'll be placing extra information into `interfaces.d/*`, I'd expect those files to be sourced *after* my existing interfaces.

The remainder of the `/etc/network/interfaces` (excluding comments) is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Kinda related (/ duplicate): https://serverfault.com/questions/390085/static-virtual-ip-in-debian-6-0-4?rq=1

Comment: Did my answer sufficiently answer your question? If so, could you mark is as correct and accepted? If not, please elaborate how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create "subinterfaces" that contain the additional IP addresses, e.g. in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto ens3:0
iface ens3:0 inet static
    address ...
    netmask ...
auto ens3:1
iface ens3:1 inet static
    address ...
    netmask ...
```

[This link](http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/debian/ubuntu-debian/create-sub-interface-secondary-ip-address-ubuntu-debian/) points to an older article (from 2013) so it might be there are now better ways to add additional IP addresses.